# Python Flask route with url as parameter

Tags: python, flask, routes, rest

Is there a way to add a url to a Flask route.
Something like this:

```
@product.route('/product/<string:url>', methods=['DELETE'])
```

And the call should be:

```
http://localhost:5001/api/product/https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B086383HC7/ref=s9_acss_bw_cg_PCLTMC_3b1_w?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-2&pf_rd_r=QPQKT152QWFXP9BS3DNV&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=16fd1ce3-bb83-4ad9-831c-81f994c41e9e&pf_rd_i=565108
```

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention that my app is a rest service, so i'm testing my route with Postman. There the 404 error occurs

Another way is to add the url in the requeste body as a json.

Answer (score 0):

You can `quoteplus` the url before appending:

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus, unquote_plus

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B086383HC7/ref=s9_acss_bw_cg_PCLTMC_3b1_w?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-2&pf_rd_r=QPQKT152QWFXP9BS3DNV&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=16fd1ce3-bb83-4ad9-831c-81f994c41e9e&pf_rd_i=565108'

print(quote_plus(url))

>>> https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fgp%2Fproduct%2FB086383HC7%2Fref%3Ds9_acss_bw_cg_PCLTMC_3b1_w%3Fpf_rd_m%3DATVPDKIKX0DER%26pf_rd_s%3Dmerchandised-search-2%26pf_rd_r%3DQPQKT152QWFXP9BS3DNV%26pf_rd_t%3D101%26pf_rd_p%3D16fd1ce3-bb83-4ad9-831c-81f994c41e9e%26pf_rd_i%3D565108

new_url = f"/product/{quote_plus(url)}"
```

Of course, you'll need to `unquote_plus()` it in the view.

If you're creating the url on the web in javascript, use `encodeURIComponent(url)` to make the url string:

```
const url = 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B086383HC7/ref=s9_acss_bw_cg_PCLTMC_3b1_w?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-2&pf_rd_r=QPQKT152QWFXP9BS3DNV&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=16fd1ce3-bb83-4ad9-831c-81f994c41e9e&pf_rd_i=565108'

console.log(encodeURIComponent(url));

>>> https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fgp%2Fproduct%2FB086383HC7%2Fref%3Ds9_acss_bw_cg_PCLTMC_3b1_w%3Fpf_rd_m%3DATVPDKIKX0DER%26pf_rd_s%3Dmerchandised-search-2%26pf_rd_r%3DQPQKT152QWFXP9BS3DNV%26pf_rd_t%3D101%26pf_rd_p%3D16fd1ce3-bb83-4ad9-831c-81f994c41e9e%26pf_rd_i%3D565108
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that my app is a rest service, so i'm testing my route with Postman. There the 404 error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

yes but you should validate the url in the get method and make sure its safe, then this is how you can do it **dynamically**:

```py
from flask import request
@product.route('/product/')
def product():
    url = request.args.get('url')
    # rest of code
```

and you must add `?url` to your call:

```
http://localhost:5001/api/product/?url=https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0863...
```

i hope you find it useful

Comment: This uses a query string, which was not the original question.  Also, how would this method handle a url that also has a query string?

Comment: the person asking the question wants to add url in flask route and most probably he wants get and handle the url! also you can store the url in a variable and handle query strings with `urllib.parse.parse_qs`